# scripts/install_dependencies run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to Deploy an application from GitHub.I have created a repository in Github with appspec.yml.
The following is the code of my appspec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /index.html
    destination: /var/www/html/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

I am getting an error while deploying the application

> Script at specified location: scripts/install_dependencies run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you also share the script inside the install_dependencies.sh file? Something in there is throwing an error and hence it exited with code 1

Comment: #!/bin/bash
sudo apt install apache2           
These two lines are in the install_dependencies.sh
Thank you

Comment: Please don't include logs (or any other text data) as images, just copy-paste the contents into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install_dependencies script exits with code 1, because Apache installation for permission before installing Apache.

To get around this problem use the -y flag with the install command inside your install_dependencies.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me. 
I have another doubt in the appspec.yml file what is the destination meant to (in files)? which destination we have to give 
                                                               files:
                                                                  - source: /index.html
                                                                    destination: ?

Comment: Would be great if you can ask a separate question for this and add the link here :) Stackoverflow is a Q&A site and the focus is on building a repository of good question and answers! Thanks.

Comment: Sure ! Thanks for your help :)